# Why does adding a border change the height calculation?

Tags: html, css

I have got two `div`containers one with a border and one without the border.
Inside both containers I got a `p` paragraph with a margin of `1em`.

Obviously both container should have the same height.
Surprisingly that is not the case for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE.

[image]

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jam3B/)

**CSS:**

```
p { display: block; margin: 1em }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first `p` element's margins are [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) with its parent `div`. This means the margins on the `p` element are combining with the zero margins on your `div`, causing them to cross the boundaries of the `div`. As a result, the height of the `div` is reported to be the same as its `p` child.

In the second group of elements, margin collapse is prevented when you add a border. This causes the parent `div` to completely contain both the `p` element as well as its margins. So the height of the `div` becomes the sum of the `p` element's height and its vertical margins.

Remember that `p` elements have default vertical margins, and that most block elements have no fixed height (i.e. are `height: auto` by default), so they'll only be as tall as is necessary to fit their contents. When a child's margins are collapsing with its parent's margins, those margins are *not* included when calculating the parent's height.